# Radio buttons only one required validation and error message

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to allow only one option to be checked of a group of radio buttons, and to validate when no option is checked by displaying an error message.

This is what I did [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/w33c4qxo/)

```js
(function($, W, D) {
  var JQUERY4U = {};

  JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
    setupFormValidation: function() {
      //form validation rules

      // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
      $("#requestAr").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
          requestType: {
            checkType: true,
          },
          requester: {
            required: true,
          },
        },
        messages: {
          requester: {
            required: "Enter your name",
          },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
      });

    }
  };

  $(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkType', function(value) {
      return ($(value).is(':checked'));
    }, "Choose request type");
  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I couldn't make it work, even when I checked one option the validation error still displayed and reject submitting the form

Comment: Give all the radio inputs the same `name`. Check one by default. Then you don't need any validation at all. Also be careful of leaving the trailing commas in your objects - they will break IE

Comment: Your fiddle have: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function**

Comment: Thank You Guys ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Html:

```
<form id="frm">
  <div class="formLayout">
    <div class="required">
      <label>Request Type</label>
      <legend>
        Article
        <input type="radio" name="requestType" value="Article"/>
        e-Article
        <input type="radio" name="requestType" value="eArticle"/>
        Chapter
        <input type="radio" name="requestType" value="Chapter"/>
      </legend>
    </div>
    <!-- Error label -->
    <label id="requestType-error" class="error" for="requestType"></label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#frm').validate({
    rules: {
    requestType: {
        required: true
    }
  }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/33/)